# In my sbmissions page the user has to get the data which is added by that particular user

Tags: python, django

I am trying to develop a website using django. In my website there is my submissions page if the user added any data to the website he can edit or delete the data which is added only by him. But my problem is when the user is logged in and viewed the my submissions page the user is getting all the data including which is added by some other users.
views.py

```
@login_required
def submissions(request):
    tasks = listing_model.objects.all()
    form = listing_form()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = listing_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('submissions')
    context = {'tasks':tasks, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'submission.html', context)

def updateTask(request, pk):
    task = listing_model.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = listing_form(instance=task)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = listing_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('submissions')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'updatepg.html', context)

def deleteTask(request, pk):
    item = listing_model.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item.delete()
        return redirect('submissions')
    context = {'item':item}
    return render(request, 'deletepg.html', context)
```

submission.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
<div class ="container">
<div class="todo-list">
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <div class="item-row">
    <div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'updatepg' task.id %}">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'deletepg' task.id %}">Delete</a>
            <span> {{ task.title }}</span>
            
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just add `user=request.user`

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
tasks = listing_model.objects.all()
```

Instead of getting all objects, filter by the currently logged in user:

```
tasks = listing_model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I am getting field error. Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: address, city, id, image, phone, pincode, price, rooms, sqfoot, state, title

Comment: You need to add user to your `Task` model as a `ForeignKey`